# how to Wrap Text in renderTable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

At one point in my code, I have:

```
   output$summaryTable <- renderTable({
      createData()$summary
    },align='lll')
```

However, `createData()$summary[2,1]` and `createData()$summary[2,2]` are both very long and thus the table has a very wide scroller. What's the best way to fix it so that it wraps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if Your question is still valid, here is one solution for Your problem:

```
output$summaryTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(createData()$summary,
options = list(columnDefs = list(list(targets = 1,render = JS("function(data, type, row, meta) {","return type === 'display' && data.length > 10 ?","'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 8) + '...</span>' : data;","}")))))})
```

if the row has more then 10 characters (`data.length > 10`), dataTable is going to display only 8 (`data.substr(0, 8)`) of them:

**rowwithlongname -> rowwithl...**

when you get mouse over the row then the full name is displayed

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate your table but it seems that you will have to add some css to format the table the way you want.

You would probably have to add in your ui.r something like:

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(
    HTML("#summaryTable table tr td {word-wrap: break-word}")
  )
)
```

I could test for validity of my answer if I could replicate your table.